# Парсинг Beautiful soup 4 не правильный вывод: лишние пробелы, текст

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautiful-soup

Здравствуйте, имеется участок кода html, который я пытаюсь спарсить с помощью Beatiful Soup 4

```
<dt>
    Бренд
</dt>
<dd class="sep">
    Nubia <a class="foward-link" href="">мобильные телефоны Nubia <i></i></a>
</dd>
```

Код:

```
company=soup.find("dd",{"class": "sep"})
print("Компания: ",company.contents[0])
```

Но вместо ожидаемого названия, выдает название с табуляцией
[image: Вывод сообщения]
Хотя по коду название должно быть впритык к компании. Как исправить? Может у beatiful Soup есть какой то метод?

Прилагаю также скриншот с текстового редактора, для просмотра табуляции в коде
[image: Табуляция]

Comment: старайтесь одной проблемой на вопрос ограничиваться, чтобы более информативные ответы получить и чтобы для большего круга людей вопрос был бы полезным. Первая часть  вопроса у вас никак со второй не связана. Про производительность отдельно следует спрашивать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
company = soup.find("dd", {"class": "sep"})
text = company.contents[0]
print("Компания: ", text.strip())
```

Comment: спасибо, а по поводу других модулей вы ничего не можете сказать?

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) По поводу скорости сказать мне особо нечего. Думаю, что основные тормоза у вас от Selenium. И можно ещё попробовать загрузку сделать асинхронной.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить только первый текстовый фрагмент (без текста внутри ссылки итд), игнорируя окружающий пробел, можно `dd.stripped_strings` использовать:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
dd = soup.find('dd', 'sep')
print(next(dd.stripped_strings))
```

Для сравнения, `dd.get_text()` вернул бы весь текст, вложенный в `<dd>` и его потомков рекурсивно:

```
print(dd.get_text(strip=True))
```

Стоит заметить, что `next(dd.strings)` более устойчив к небольшим изменениям в html-разметке по сравнению с `dd.contents[0]`, который (первый ребёнок `dd` элемента) не обязан быть текстом (`NavigableString`).

Comment: О! Не знал про stripped_strings.